# Angular 2: setTimeout for everything?

Tags: jquery, angular, settimeout

I've seen examples where code will be wrapped in a setTimeout function to avoid templates/components from being generated without the data they are waiting on. I want to use the jQuery bootstrap-multiselect to display a list of organizations.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this._panelService.getOrgs()
    .subscribe(
      orgs => this.orgs = orgs,
      error => alert('There was an error connecting to the API'),
      () => setTimeout(() => jQuery('#organizations').multiselect(), 0));
}
```

I've used it other places as well. In this case, I'm calling the API after a delete in order to trigger a change in an *ngFor:

```
deleteBoard(panelId: number, boardId: number) {
  this._boardService.deleteBoard(panelId, boardId)
    .subscribe(
      boards => this.panel.boards = boards,
      error => alert('There was an error contacting the API.'),
      () => setTimeout(this._boardService.getAvailableRanks(panelId)
        .subscribe(ranks => this.updatedRanks = ranks), 0));
}
```

*ngFor doesn't detect the change unless I use setTimeout. What did I miss?

I'm using beta 14.

Answer (score 7):

Angular change detection will automatically run after each asynchronous event, IF that asynchronous event was monkey-patched by Zone.js.  It is during change detection that NgFor bindings are checked for changes, and if any changes are found, the DOM is updated.

I assume `deleteBoard()` uses some kind of asynchronous event, but that event is probably not monkey-patched by Zone.js.  `setTimeout()` is monkey-patched, so calling it will trigger change detection.

Instead of `setTimeout()`, you could also inject [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) and call its `detectChanges()` method, which will detect changes on this component and its descendants.  This is another way to manually trigger change detection.

However, there is a difference between the two approaches.  With `setTimeout()`, the browser gets a chance to render the view before your callback function is called.  And sometimes you need this.  With `detectChanges()`, change detection runs before the browser gets a chance to render the view.  Use `detectChanges()` if you can since it is more efficient (one less change detection cycle is executed).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` needs to be able to do its work. For this you need to enqueue the call to `jQuery` into the event queue using `setTimeout`. If you run it synchronous, `*ngFor` doesn't get a time slot to process the updates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for the delete call to be complete and then reload you ranks, I would leverage the `flatMap` operator:

```
deleteBoard(panelId: number, boardId: number) {
  this._boardService.deleteBoard(panelId, boardId)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .flatMap((board) => {
      this.panel.boards = boards,
      return this._boardService.getAvailableRanks(panelId)
        .map(res => res.json());
    })
    .subscribe(ranks => this.updatedRanks = ranks));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need to include zone.js.
It will help Angular realize changes have occurred (think of it almost like the way digest was in Angular1)

```
   "zone.js": "0.6.10" // add it in dependencies
```